# Add category IDs to product collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, collection, product-collection

I am injecting this collection into my model:

```
\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $prodCollection
```

I use it to create an array of all products but I want to add the products category ids to the results.

I tried:

```
$prodItems = $this->prodCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->addCategoryIds()->getData();
```

This doesn't include the category IDs in results.  I am trying to avoid having to load the product through the product repository and calling the method to get categories on every single product as that would be a very expensive operation.

Whats the cheapest way to get the product categories?

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $productCollection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('description');
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $productCollection->addCategoryIds();
    $productCollection->load();
```

This works absolutely fine for me... I'm not sure what getData is supossed to do. I just go throught it with:

```
    foreach ($productCollection as $item) {
```